# How to install Rails 4.2.0,Ruby 2.1.5 and PostgreSQL In Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I need one help.I need to install `Rails 4.2.0,ruby 2.1.5 and PostgreSQL` database In my ubuntu server. I need the proper steps to install all those in my server.I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Please help me.

Comment: you want a setup guide?

Comment: yes,I need to set up all those.Not exactly the guide but the proper steps.

Comment: i fear it'll make the question too broad

Comment: What...? Ok can i get any reference link.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely take a look at the GoRails instructions for installing Rails. They are by far my favorite...
https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04

As far as installing it on Ubuntu Server. It's fairly straight forward. Simply install OpenSSH-Server on the server itself...

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then run `ifconfig` to get the server IP address.
Then you can log onto the server from a remote computer with `ssh server_user_name@sever_ip_address`

Then you can proceed to Follow the instructions from GoRails to install Rails on the Server.

Or you can just install rails locally from within the Local Server Console (vs Remote Console) if you wish.